# Phonegap - Add Java Library

Tags: java, android, mobile, cordova

I have a Phonegap app already created and deployed. I want to add an "external" Java library for handling mag-stripe data (mag data received from a mobile credit card swipe). How can I go about including this library so I may handle this data in my native app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop a Cordova/Phonegap plugin that exposes a javascript API that interacts with the native library.

The documentation for creating a plugin is here:

[Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)